# Не с прилагательными

Tags: орфография

"Не назначенный" - как правильно: вместе или раздельно?

Answer (score 1):

Это не прилагательное, а причастие. Может писаться слитно, если нет зависимого слова и противопоставления с союзом "а". Не назначенный, а выбранный начальник. Никем не назначенный срок. Но: неназначенный директор зря ругает персонал.

Answer (score 1):

Это полное страдательное причастие, пишется слитно, так как нет зависимого слова или противопоставления с союзом а.